# Cannot resolve symbols in Android Studio and the code is okay

Tags: android

I know that this question was asked here a few times, but everything i have tried from answers they gave there didn't work for me.

Also i need to mention that i have tried File - Invilidate Cache and Restart and it didn't work..

Here is my build gradle(Maybe something there is wrong):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dusandimitrijevic.geomondo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar:3.1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three issues.

1. Your `targetSdkVersion` is higher than your `compileSdkVersion`.
2. You are using a version of the support library that requires a minimum of API 22 to compile with.
3. You are not specifying the version of recyclerview, so it will import the latest one, which requires API 23 to compile with.

The fix is to set `compileSdkVersion` to 23. That SHOULD fix your missing symbols issue.

Comment: I have changed and still didn't solve my problem. I'm getting again "cannot resolve symbols"

Comment: I didn't see you have edited your answer. I will try to do that.

Comment: You may need to also update `buildToolsVersion` to 23.0.1

Comment: Well now i'm getting everywhere errors because i can't use with higher versions of API BasinNameValuePair and NameValuePair.

Comment: Are you using the apache http client?

Comment: Wow i can't believe that this issue was some bracket i forgot to delete. But thank you for quick respond. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91676/discussion-between-dusan-dimitrijevic-and-phxhawke).